# How can I download photos from old computer when I don't remember password

Tags: windows

I have an old computer that I am getting ready to toss and I would like to download some old photos and possibly files, but I don't remember my password.  It had windows 7 and I may have updated to windows 8.  Would like to review and make sure there isn't anything on it that I want before I pull the memory cards and trash it.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any encryption in use, or is it simply a user login password you can't remember?

Comment: Pull the hard drive from the PC, then use a sata to usb cable or dock to connect it to your new PC, now you can browse the files on it and copy any you need to the PC you are using.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer is not encrypted, you can pull out the hard drive and connect a sata to usb cord to the hard drive and connect it to your computer and browse the files like a flash drive. You can also connect the hard drive to another computer if you have spare sata connections.

You can also make a windows bootable environment that you can boot into to retrieve the files, or change the administrator password on the laptop.

Both of these options will require a little bit of work, especially if you are not the most technical. The first one will require to pull out the hard drive out of your laptop, while the second one will require you to create a bootable USB with a portable environment (PE). The second one will require you to figure out whether your bios is legacy or UEFI.

If you decide you want to do the bootable usb, I can direct you to a guide on how to create a bootable usb but I will need you to figure out if your bios is set on legacy or uefi.